# Python List Maker

Tags: python

I would like to make a program that would help others who sometimes make longs lists.

The program would take the users text file, for example:

```
1
2
3
```

The program would then turn that into a list like this

```
listname = ["1","2","3"]
```

I feel that this would be useful for some people out there who create long lists.

I am looking for someone to tell me what would need to be done, im guessing I would need to use a for loop and split the text file up some how. Thanks

Comment: What you are describing is already built into Python. I suggest you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Is this for programmers writing long list literals, or is it for programs that need to read input from files?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's not quite built-in; you still need to strip newlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python almost already does that. You can open a file and read all its lines as follows:

```
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
    long_list = [line.strip() for line in input_file]
```

[str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing whitespace characters removed.

If you want to read all the lines into a list without removing any of the whitespaces then Python does that out of the box:

```
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
    long_list = input_file.readlines()
```

You can go ahead and put that into a function for others to use but I'm not sure how useful it would be.

Comment: Leading and trailing *whitespace* characters are removed.

Comment: `line.rstrip('\n')` or `line.rstrip('\n\r')` for trailing newlines.